# How Does String Startswith Work

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have String Like

```
var response = GetTransport();
var lowersearch = "XYZ Transport Services";
```

I have Linq Query Like

```
transport= BuildTransport(response)
            .Where(r => r.TransportName.ToLower().StartsWith(lowersearch))
            .ToList();
```

for this query am getting a count as 0

FYI 
     r.TransportName will return a string like **"XYZ Transportation Services"**

Comment: isn't the problem obvious?

Comment: The value of `lowersearch` isn't all lower case, so how do you expect a lower case string to start with it?

Comment: @JonSkeet Even i tried with lowersearch.ToLower(); but am still facing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are calling `ToLower` on `r.TransportName` which converts all the letters lower-case
2. `"XYZ Transportation Services"` != `"XYZ Transport Services"`

Solutions:

1. Don't call `ToLower` on `r.TransportName` or call it on `lowerserach` as well
2. if **Transportation Services** wasn't a typo, don't expect them to be equal.

Comment: Even i tried lowersearch.ToLower(); but still the Count is zero

Comment: @SundarRajan there is a difference between `Transport` and `Transportation` isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah tats why am stuck any other way?

Comment: Are you looking for fuzzy string matching, @Sundar? How close should the phrases be before they match, or how far apart before that match no more?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta In my Real scenario am getting that lowersearch from the database for example only i put it in variable so am asking like without changing the string in database is there any other way to get this problem solve

Comment: The two strings you're comparing are different, @Sundar, so no. Unless you're happy with just using "XYZ Transport", or something like that, as `lowersearch`.